# Embedding custom stylesheets/JS on specific websites

Tags: google-chrome, web, chromium

Is there an extension for Google Chrome / Chromium that would allow me to embed custom stylesheets or execute custom JS code when a specific website is opened?

If not, is it possible to develop one?

Of course, a bookmarklet might do the same job, but it has to be clicked on each entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) is a nice extension for modifying CSS, but it won't help you with Javascript. You'll probably need two separate extensions, for CSS and JS.

Comment: Stylebot seems super-elegant and I don't think I'm going to need JS that often anyway.

Answer (score 5):

[TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) gives you the ability to run custom javascript on pages.  As far as I can tell you can import GreaseMonkey scripts for firefox into it.

Answer (score 1):

GreaseMonkey does exactly what you're looking for, but it's a Firefox extension. I found what seems to be an equivalent for Chrome [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/details), though I haven't used it myself.